# Error in createIndexes: Failed to send "createIndexes" command with database "mydb": Failed to read 4 bytes: socket error or timeout

Tags: c, libmongoc

I have been recently migrating python code to C using libmongoc-1.0 1.15. I am having troubles creating indexes. I am following the example [here](http://mongoc.org/libmongoc/current/create-indexes.html). I think it has something to do with me using MongoDB 4.2 since it changed all indexes to be background by default, but I thought version 1.15.3 of libmongoc does support everything new in 4.2.

```
{ "createIndexes" : "mycol", "indexes" : [ { "key" : { "x" : 1, "y" : 1 }, "name" : "x_1_y_1" } ] }
{ }
Error in createIndexes: Failed to send "createIndexes" command with database "mydb": Failed to read 4 bytes: socket error or timeout
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this C ? Does not look like C , what is it ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what are you talking about. What is not C and what does not look like C?

Comment: OK , can you compile it ?

Answer (score 1):

```
"failed to send "createIndexes" command with database "testdb" mongodb error"
```

I was having a similar issue, in our case, one of the replica sets was having the issue after fixing the issue related replica set and restarting the cluster issue solved